# Unbrick "hardbricked" Moto G8 Power

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, unbricking, motorola-moto-g

I tried to install LineageOS on my Moto G8 Power. After a reboot to recovery mode (done because the installer said it was needed for the a something) it didn't boot.

All I get is that

> a QUSB(...) device is available...

I have tried all button combo's.
Is it possible to unbrick it?
ADB and Fastboot wont see the device.

Answer (score 0):

Your device is in QDL mode and moto devices use a blankflash method.

Try this if not already done: https://xdaforums.com/t/request-blankflash-for-g8-power.4172795/

Comment: Well okay, but how can I blankflash it? Because whilst I have been searching through the internet, I have not been able to find a way that works, qboot won't see the phone and I have not been able to find an other solution.